# where is the bugtracker of Git?

Tags: git, bug-tracking

I was searching for the bug tracker for Git but I didn't really found it on [their homepage](http://git-scm.com/) and their issue tracker on [GitHub](https://github.com/gitster/git) is disabled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Git bugs should be reported to: git@vger.kernel.org as indicated on the [Git Community page](http://git-scm.com/community). The mailing list archive can be [viewed and searched here](http://dir.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git).

Comment: So it means there is no bug tracker?

Comment: @Albert: The mailing list _is_ where git bugs are tracked.

Comment: Tracking means that every bug has a well defined state and the system usually allows database like requests (such as "give me all open bugs which are marked important"). Esp., I know about a specific bug and want to know if it was reported, who is working on it, etc. There was a thread about it [here](http://lists-archives.org/git/719832-git-mac-os-x-and-german-special-characters.html) but it isn't really clear from there about the state.

Comment: @Albert: Looking at the email thread it doesn't look like the questions about the patch (suitability and licensing) were answered, so it never got to a state where it could be included. Checking the log for `name-hash.c` certainly confirms this.

Comment: This email address no longer appears on http://git-scm.com/ - AMEND, I've made an edit to point to where it is