# Git, Mac OS X and accented characters

Tags: macos, git, utf-8

On MacOSX with Git, there is a problem with different UTF8 representations of filename encodings. (Similar problems also exists in SVN.)

There is a patch for this [here](http://lists-archives.org/git/719832-git-mac-os-x-and-german-special-characters.html).

I wonder if there is any bug report (in their bug tracker which I haven't found yet) with any discussion about why this haven't been pulled yet or if anyone is working on it, etc.

Comment: File the bug report! This question will be more appropriate at their mailing list.

Comment: @Yuji: As far as I understood (from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7620050/where-is-the-bugtracker-of-git)), a mail to the mailinglist *is* filling a bug report. And my linked patch is a mail in that mailinglist. So that is the actual report. But I'm not really sure where to go from there. Or if there is another *real* bug tracker somewhere.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Enable `core.precomposeunicode` on the Mac

```
git config --global core.precomposeunicode true
```

Then reclone the repository. For this to work, you need to have at least Git 1.7.12, which is bundled with Xcode 4.6.

That's it.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! Unfortunately, after running that command, my `énoncé.js` file still shows up as `"\303\251nonc\303\251.js"`, when I run `$ git status`.  Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

This problem is very known and very understood, see, for example [this one](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/70688). Linus have some voice on this thread too.

There are some patch that paper over the problem, and no developer care enough / have to skill to fix it in the proper way. Maybe, i guess, it is impossible to fix this without breaking old commits.

Comment: In other words, Linus says that Osx filesystem is stupid. I share this thought. "A" != "a". The HFS should be fixed, not git.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it was stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7620050/where-is-the-bugtracker-of-git) that there is no bug tracker and the common way is to send a mail to their mailing list.

I just did that [here](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/182548). And I messed up the thread a bit. :) Further discussion is [here](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/182552).

Comment: Thanks. By the way I had almost the same conversation in this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5581857/git-and-the-umlaut-problem-on-mac-os-x

Answer (score 0):

Besides the patch there is a [workaround by translating Mac OS X the encoding for git](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7322034/1309300)! that seems to work for me.